# Getting CORS Error when the response is not 200 (Django + ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, django

Getting the below error when sending a 401 (un-authorized) response. As per the error, when I change it to 200, it works well. But here I need to send 401 itself.
I went through almost all the related questions in stackoveflow, but nothing helped.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8888/employees/api/fetch/home/data/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Frontend :  **ReactJS**

Backend : **Django**

Error:
[image]

ReactJS - Code to consume the service:

```
export async function post(url, requestBody = {}, token=true) {
    try{
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'token' : token ? window.sessionStorage.getItem("token") : null,
                'user-type' : token ? window.sessionStorage.getItem("user-type") : null,
                'identifier' : token ? window.sessionStorage.getItem("identifier") : null,
            },
            body: requestBody ? JSON.stringify(requestBody) : "{}"
        };
        console.log("Requesting POST : url is : ", url," Content Is: ", requestOptions)
        const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
        return await response.json()
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Service Failed: ", e)
        return {
            status: false,
            messages: ["Service Failed. Please try after sometime."]
        }
    }
}
```

Django - Settings.py

```
#TODO
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

CUSTOM_HEADERS = (
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'token',
    'user-type',
    'identifier',
    'device-id',
    'is-mobile'
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + CUSTOM_HEADERS

#TODO
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

#TODO
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',
)

#TODO
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'middleware.authenticate.Authenticate',

    #Cors
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
```

Django - Response Builder Class:

```
def build_response(response_code, message, data=None):
    if (message == None or message == ""):
        message = []
    else:
        if (hasattr(message, '__len__') and (not isinstance(message, str))):
            pass
        else:
            message = [message]
    fdata = {
        "status" : True if response_code < 300 else False,
        "messages" : message,
        "data" :data
    }
    resp =  Response(fdata, response_code)
    
    cust_headers = (','.join(str(each_hdr) for each_hdr in CUSTOM_HEADERS))
    allowed_origins = (','.join(str(each_origin) for each_origin in CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS))

    resp['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = allowed_origins
    resp["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, '+cust_headers
    return resp
```